# Displaying a List in Textbox

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a list of object to create a league table.

Here is the `class` created for the `object`:

```
public class LeagueRow
{
    public String teamName { get; set; }
    public String managerName { get; set; }
    public Int32 played { get; set; }
    public Int32 won { get; set; }
    public Int32 draw { get; set; }
    public Int32 lost { get; set; }
    public Int32 goalsFor { get; set; }
    public Int32 goalsAgainst { get; set; }
    public Int32 goalDifference { get; set; }
    public Int32 points { get; set; }

}
```

I am then trying to add each row, and display each row in `literal1` to see the contents of the list. Seen here:

```
goalDifference = goalsFor - goalsAgainst;

List<LeagueRow> leagueTeamRow = new List<LeagueRow>();
leagueTeamRow.Add(new LeagueRow { teamName = dReader["teamName"].ToString(), managerName = dReader["ManagerFirstName"].ToString() + " " + dReader["ManagerSurname"].ToString(), played = gamesPlayed, won = won, draw = draw, lost = lost, goalsFor = goalsFor, goalsAgainst = goalsAgainst, goalDifference = goalDifference, points = points });

for (int i = 0; i < leagueTeamRow.Count; i++)
{
    Literal1.Text += (leagueTeamRow[i].ToString());
}
```

I am having an issue as the correct number of `rows` are displaying in the `literal`, however the data just has the name of the project and the row name like: `PROJECTNAME.LeagueRow` multiple times.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use a `ListBox` for things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding the `object` to the literal, when you call `ToString()` on an object you will just get the type/namespace, i suspect you want the property. You need to do something like: -

```
Literal1.Text += (leagueTeamRow[i].teamName);
```

Obviously replacing `teamName` with the correct property.

Comment: Or create a custom .ToString() method :-) But yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Override the ToString method of your `LeagueRow` class to return the right thing to display (for example, the team and managername).

```
 public class LeagueRow
    {
        public String teamName { get; set; }
        public String managerName { get; set; }
        public Int32 played { get; set; }
        public Int32 won { get; set; }
        public Int32 draw { get; set; }
        public Int32 lost { get; set; }
        public Int32 goalsFor { get; set; }
        public Int32 goalsAgainst { get; set; }
        public Int32 goalDifference { get; set; }
        public Int32 points { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("TeamName: {0}, ManagerName: {1}", teamName, managerName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LeagueRow.ToString()` method is the base method from `Object`.

You either need to overide the `ToString()` method or concatenate the strings you want to display.

Overide:

```
public class LeagueRow
{
    public String teamName { get; set; }
    public String managerName { get; set; }
    public Int32 played { get; set; }
    public Int32 won { get; set; }
    public Int32 draw { get; set; }
    public Int32 lost { get; set; }
    public Int32 goalsFor { get; set; }
    public Int32 goalsAgainst { get; set; }
    public Int32 goalDifference { get; set; }
    public Int32 points { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("TeamName: {0}, ManagerName: {1}", teamName, managerName);
    }
}
```

concatenate:

```
goalDifference = goalsFor - goalsAgainst;

List<LeagueRow> leagueTeamRow = new List<LeagueRow>();
leagueTeamRow.Add(new LeagueRow { teamName = dReader["teamName"].ToString(), managerName = dReader["ManagerFirstName"].ToString() + " " + dReader["ManagerSurname"].ToString(), played = gamesPlayed, won = won, draw = draw, lost = lost, goalsFor = goalsFor, goalsAgainst = goalsAgainst, goalDifference = goalDifference, points = points });

for (int i = 0; i < leagueTeamRow.Count; i++)
{
    Literal1.Text += (leagueTeamRow[i].teamName+"\t"+leagueTeamRow[i].managerName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is just fine, *however*, you need to override the `ToString` method in your class and define there what you want the string to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data reader you are using, if you have bunch of rows in the data reader, you must loop through it to pick the right value. Something like

```
    dr[i]["teamName"];
```